# Unused frame(window) management

Tags: java, gui

I'm rewriting my game now using software designing patterns and want to do the code, most correct I can. While implementing MVC(Model View Controller) I got a question which I would like to discuss or to hear some opinions of experts.
The question is about management of unused frames... For example next sequence of windows:
ResourceLoadingWindow -> LoginWindow -> GameWindow
Definetly that I don't want to reuse ResourceLoadingWindow , since I'm using Java Applet and I don't see any situation when I will need to reuse it. The different story is about LoginWindow, which can be reused a lot of times, because some player would want to Logout and come back again in few minutes for example. I would like to know, following the MVC structure, should I destroy window, removing it from ContentPane or just hide? Maybe I need to unregister it from controller or I shouldn't do so?

Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say hide it. Then it's loaded and you can just call it whenever. If you're changing accounts then why load another copy, right? It's pretty lightweight though, I bet, so use whichever is easiest for now.

Comment: Well I was discussing MVC implementation on Stackoverflow and it seems (in my case) it more reasonable to create and destroy unused frames always. But anyways thanks for advice.